# Executing multiple unix commands at once

Tags: unix

Here are my commands for a task.

```
find -name myname.tar
tar -xvf myname.tar
rm -r myname/*
```

These multi line commands are working fine, but I need a one line command. Then I used this command,

```
find -name myname.tar | tar -xvf myname.tar | rm -r myname/*
```

I get this error:

```
"rm -r myname/*
rm: cannot remove `myname/*': No such file or directory "
```

can some one help me in this?

Thanks

Comment: Good question! I've been looking for this a while now!!

Comment: Isn't the effet the same though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most possibly you are looking for a way to execute the next command, if the previous one ran without an error.

- In UNIX errors from command line tools typically change the program's exit status
- In most UNIX shells, the `&&` operator checks the exit status and moves on, if it is `0` (for OK)

So what you seem to want is

```
find -name myname.tar && tar -xvf myname.tar && rm -r myname/*
```

Comment: I have a process which I want to execute in the background, so I place a `&` at the end of the command. If I place `&&` after I get `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common ways to do this:

Join the commands together with a semicolon `;` which will run the commands one after the other.

```
echo "Hello"; false; echo "There";
>> Hello
>> There
```

The other is join commands with a `&&`

The `&&` will ONLY do the next command if the one before it had a zero exit code.

```
echo "Hello" && false && echo "There";
>> Hello
```

The '|' symbol does something different entirely.  It runs the two commands, feeling the standard out `stdout` of the one into the standard in `stdin` of the other.  (`wc -w` counts the number of words in `stdin`.)

```
echo "Two Words" | wc -w
>> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

What you were using (|) is called a peer, which passes data from one command to another. for ex.:

```
$ cat test.php | grep '<'
<?php
```

to run several commands one after another you can use ';':

```
echo 123; echo 456
```

or if you want your commands to depend on each others success, you can '&&':

```
$ eho 123; echo 456
eho: command not found
456

$ eho 123 && echo 456
eho: command not found
```